# Find a a value in a multidimentional array, and return a value from the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find a value in a milti array's array, and after finding it, I want to return a different key, not sure how to explain it further.

I have an array:

```
tempArray( [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 18460
        [field_id] => 14
        [parent_id] => 165
        [custom_tab_field_id] => 17775
        [status] => 0
        [field_type] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 18461
        [field_id] => 2
        [parent_id] => 165
        [custom_tab_field_id] => 17776
        [status] => 0
        [field_type] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 18462
        [field_id] => 12
        [parent_id] => 165
        [custom_tab_field_id] => 17777
        [status] => 2
        [field_type] => 2
    ))
```

I'm trying to find the array by [custom_tab_field_id], and return the current's array [status].

I created a function that should do just that, but it's always returning 0.

The function:

```
function searchForStatus($id, $array){
        
        $returnedStatus = "0";
        foreach ($array as $key => $val){
            if ($val['custom_tab_field_id'] == $id){
                return $returnedStatus = $array[$key]['status'];
            }
        }
        return $returnedStatus;
    }
```

and then simply call for the function by passing values

```
$returnedStatus = searchForStatus($field['custom_tab_field_id'], $tempArr);
```

Comment: What is the _type_ of `$field['custom_tab_field_id']`? You used the `===` comparison operator for strict equality, so this would have to be an integer, otherwise it won't match any of the `custom_tab_field_id` integers from your array.

Comment: @CBroe It is integer, all the fields are integers

Comment: Integer in your database? That does not necessarily mean integer in your PHP code, depending on how exactly you fetched those values. Have you _verified_ the types of both, `$field['custom_tab_field_id']`, and the `custom_tab_field_id` entries in your array, using var_dump?

Comment: @CBroe, my bad, it is a string

Comment: @CBroe but even after changing it to == it's returning nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function, this can be easily solved and is very universal.

```
$array = [
  ['id' => 18460, 'field_id' => 14, 'parent_id' => 165, 'custom_tab_field_id' => 17775, 'status' => 0, 'field_type' => 0],
  ['id' => 18460, 'field_id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 165, 'custom_tab_field_id' => 17776, 'status' => 0, 'field_type' => 2],
  ['id' => 18460, 'field_id' => 14, 'parent_id' => 165, 'custom_tab_field_id' => 17777, 'status' => 2, 'field_type' => 2],
];

$findKey = 'custom_tab_field_id';
$getKey = 'status';
$findVal = 17777;

$arrKeyValue = array_column($array,$getKey,$findKey);

$status = $arrKeyValue[$findVal];  //2
```

The solution contains no error handling and only shows the principle.
$arrKeyValue is a array how:

```
array (
  17775 => 0,
  17776 => 0,
  17777 => 2,
)
```

try self on https://3v4l.org/SnVM4

Answer (score 1):

you can use `array-filter` function to solve it. i.e.

```
$a1 = [
    ['id' => 1, 'status', 'active'], 
    ['id' => 2, 'status', 'in-active']
];

$search = 2;

print_r(array_filter($a1, function ($object) use ($search) {
    return $object['id'] == $search;
}));
```

it will return the whole array from the array that matches the `search` id.

you can also write a function for that

```
function search($data, $searchValue, $searchField, $returnField) {

    $filter = array_filter($data, function ($object) use ($searchValue, $searchField) {
      return $object[$searchField] == $searchValue;
    });

   return count($filter) > 0 ? $filter[0][$returnField] : null;

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement it into my code and figuring what is what, will return to you with what I get, ty